# Comparing ethers BigNumber does not work

Tags: ethers.js, testing, bignumber, chai

I'm testing the value of a BigNumber returned from a function call to a contract and its not working as expected.

I have this

```
const { BigNumber } = require('ethers');
...
const totalSupply = await token.totalSupply();
expect(totalSupply).to.equal(BigNumber.from("4"));
```

This test fails with this error:

```
AssertionError: expected BigNumber { value: "4" } to equal BigNumber { value: "4" }
      + expected - actual
```

But looking at the error message it appears the expected and actual are the same. Why does this test fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this :

```js
expect(totalSupply.eq(BigNumber.from("4")).to.equal(true);
```

This is because `to.equal` internally uses the strict equality check `===` which on Objects only returns true if the two references are pointing to the same object.

Alternatively, you could also use `.deep.equal` which checks for deep equality between Objects but not as strictly as ensuring that the references point to the same instance :

```js
expect(totalSupply).to.deep.equal(ethers.BigNumber.from("4"))
```

I hope this answers your question.